# c# DateTime.Parse precision Issue

Tags: c#, datetime

Quick question about precision with DateTime.Parse in c#?

I have multiple input files that I am consolidating into one list of lines, which I will then order by DateTime.

This is fine, except the Parse function seems to handle the date incorrectly when the milliseconds is only 2 digits, in the case below it treats 09:57:44.84 as 09:57:44.840 instead of 09:57:44.084

```
            List<DateTime> lstUnOrdered = new List<DateTime>();

            lstUnOrdered.Add(DateTime.Parse("04/09/2020 09:57:44.573", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            lstUnOrdered.Add(DateTime.Parse("04/09/2020 09:57:44.84", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

            var Ordered = lstUnOrdered.OrderBy(x => x.TimeOfDay);

            foreach (var item in Ordered)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"));
            }
```

When run, you get the following Output

09/04/2020 09:57:44.573

09/04/2020 09:57:44.840

I Expected this Output

09/04/2020 09:57:44.084

09/04/2020 09:57:44.573

Any suggestions on where I may be going wrong?

Thanks

EDIT:
Based on the comments below, just a few updates:

"Fundamentally: whatever is generating these values is broken, and should be fixed. If that's impossible for you, you should patch the data before parsing it, by inserting extra 0s where necessary. "

-- This is correct, I have no control over the data. But I do know that the order in the input file is :

09/04/2020 09:57:44.84

09/04/2020 09:57:44.573

This tells me the date should be 084 and not 840, I'm not disputing Parse is incorrect, just looking for alternatives to parse these dates with more precision, rather then having to write another method to sanitize the date string first.

I can of course split the string on the . and add 1 or 2 zeroes if needed, was hoping .Net had an inbuilt way for doing this with DateTime.Parse or alternative.

Thanks

Comment: Why shouldn't you just be able to add a 0 before the 84?

Comment: `0.84` is the same as `0.840`. `Parse` is working perfectly fine. That's how math works

Comment: `in the case below it treats 09:57:44.84 as 09:57:44.840 instead of 09:57:44.084` That is how decimals work. That isn't a bug. If I asked for $1.1 that would be 1 dollar and 10 cents. Not 1 dollar and 1 cent.

Comment: Fundamentally: whatever is generating these values is broken, and should be fixed. If that's impossible for you, you should patch the data before parsing it, by inserting extra 0s where necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the comments All. I have updated the original post.

Comment: `was hoping .Net had an inbuilt way for doing this with DateTime.Parse or alternative.` Why would .Net support a variant of mathematics that doesn't exist?

Comment: your edit make me think you are trying to ignore the words about `0.84 != 0.084`

Comment: No not suggesting 0.84 == 0.084, I have added an answer to the post, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just an Update, This will fix the issue with the bad input string in case anyone is wondering:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<DateTime> lstUnOrdered = new List<DateTime>();

        lstUnOrdered.Add(DateTime.Parse(MakeCorrectDate("04/09/2020 09:57:44.573"), 
 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        lstUnOrdered.Add(DateTime.Parse(MakeCorrectDate("04/09/2020 09:57:44.84"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

        var Ordered = lstUnOrdered.OrderBy(x => x.TimeOfDay);

        foreach (var item in Ordered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"));
        }
    }

    private static string MakeCorrectDate(string strDate)
    {
        string[] milli = strDate.Split('.');

        return milli[0] + "." + milli[1].PadLeft(3, '0');
    }
```

Comment: please do not call it bad input string

Comment: Why not? There is a log file that outputs this: "04/09/2020 09:57:44.84", when in reality the time this was logged is "04/09/2020 09:57:44.084", This makes the input string from my point of view bad and needs to be corrected [padded to 3 places of decimal]

Comment: Are you **100% sure** that .84 means .084 rather than 0.840?

Comment: Yes, 100% sure.